# Getting error while creating a Vue app using Vue CLI and giving npm start

Tags: javascript, npm, command-line, vuejs3, vue-cli

I am trying to create an app using **Vue CLI ** command -

```
npm create vue@latest
```

After **npm isnstall** i am trying to run my app using **npm run dev
** but getting below error. I would appreciate any help.

[See the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgLRy.png)

```
**(node:4344) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '??='                                           at Loader.moduleStrategy (internal/modules/esm/translators.js:145:18)                                               (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)                                                 (node:4344) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try updating your node version to 16 or higher.